# Linux machines on VM routing between two subnet

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, centos-7, vmware-player

To make a lot of tests i have several VM, one has two interfaces but it's possible it receives more. One interface uses `NAT` protocole to connect to internet, as i use VMWare, the other is on lan segment and the same for the second VM. All VM are using at least `CentOS 7`.

The network connected to internet uses `192.168.50.0/24`
The second network on lan segment uses `10.0.0.0/8`

The VM with two interfaces :

- `192.168.50.254`, `gw 192.168.50.2`
- `10.0.0.1`

The second VM : `10.0.0.2`

I can ping between both vm and ping to internet websites with the first machine. I can't ping a website on internet with the second machine.

I tried with a route on the second VM, like something as `set IPv4.routes 192.168.50.0/24 10.0.0.1` but ping never worked from second vm to `192.168.50.2` neither `8.8.8.8`.
I read something about `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` on `CentOS 6` but i would to have expert's advices, i ask myself it's perhaps old and didn't try it.

I use `NMCLI` then if possible could you give me advices with it ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is any Guest set to Host Only (isolated)?   Try (test) Bridged networking for all guests.

Comment: Hi John. One has NAT and segment, the other has segment.

Comment: What does "segment" mean?   Never heard of that by itself with reference to a Guest workstation.

Comment: Hi, segment are a part for the network configuration into vmware, it allows communication only between VM on the same segment. I have a machine that have an interface for NAT and another interface connected on a segment. the other machine is on this segment. i want to make a test with this "architecture" to simulate everything before to reproduce it in real conditions... At the end , the first machine will have a server squid and some other things.

Comment: I will take a look . I have been using VMware since V1 have have not heard that term. I think you may mean subnet. If you have more than one subnet, you have to reach the other subnet by  IP address.

Comment: It's like a subnet but it's called exactly  "lan segment", i wrote "segment". VMware doesn't give anything like a dhcp service.

Comment: VMware NAT provides an internal DHCP server for NAT Guests

Comment: yes, for NAT, but not for Lan Segment.